# Indent text in NSTextView

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have used [NSTextView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/) for user to type the input in JSON format. How do I make it work in such a way that on pressing Return/Enter it indents.

I have tried implementing it using the [NSTextStorageDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTextStorageDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intf/c:objc(pl)NSTextStorageDelegate).

```
func textStorage(textStorage: NSTextStorage, willProcessEditing editedMask: NSTextStorageEditActions, range editedRange: NSRange, changeInLength delta: Int) {

    let inputString = textStorage.string
    if editedRange.length == 1 {
        let g = inputString.characters.startIndex.advancedBy(editedRange.location)
        if "\(inputString.characters[g])" == "\n" {
            textStorage.mutableString.insertString("\n$$$$", atIndex: editedRange.location)
        }
    }
}
```

Its working fine, except on pressing enter it is creating 2 lines instead of 1.

---

For example:

(Assume pipe | is caret)

```
"Some": "Key"|
```

After pressing enter

```
"Some": "Key"
$$$$
|    //Cursor comes here. It should stay above at end of line
```

Comment: The pressed enter adds a line and `insertString` adds a line.

Comment: @Willeke. How do I avoid that?

Comment: Don't add the new line.

Comment: @Willeke ok but how do I  bring $$$$ on next line and keep the caret at the end of line and not on new line

Comment: I think it's easier to implement `textView:doCommandBySelector:`, catch `insertNewline:` and insert "\n$$$$".